# Create an array of buttons inside a bootstrap card element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My objective is to create a "grid" of buttons inside a bootstrap card element. They should be aligned to the right border of the containing card, and should be within it. I would later fill these buttons with images so that I get several image buttons.

I have written the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-20 card-deck mt-3">
  <div class="card mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded">
    <div id="buttonpanel" class="container buttonpanel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="box col">Filtri</div>
        <div class="box col">Filtri</div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="box col">Filtri</div>
        <div class="box col">Filtri</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="id" style="display: none;">2 </div>
      <h4 class="card-title">
        <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/"> Dr Jeslin's Clinic</a>
      </h4>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Label: <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/">jeslinclinic</a></h6>
      <p class="card-text">Phone: <a href="tel:9">9</a></p>
      <p class="card-text">About Clinic: Dr Jeslin's Eye Clinic is a topnotch Eye Clinic</p>
      <p class="card-text"><a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/">Homepage</a></p>
      <p class="card-text">External Website: <a href="https://mysite">https://mysite</a></p>
      <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">
        <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/editclinic" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
          <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/live" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
          <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Waiting</a>
        <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/seen" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Seen</a>
        <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/register" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
          <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Register</a>
        <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/checkin" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
          <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Checkin</a>
        <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/doctor/edit/slots/2" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
          <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i> Consultation Time</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  background-color: #3C8DBC;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.buttonpanel {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right:  0;
  margin-bottom:  0;
  margin-top:  0;
}

h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.4125rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

My result looks like this:

[image: Result]

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Droidzone/pen/XxaJYM)

Required result:

[image: Required result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grid the page, I just moved the two big `<div>` inside one row and then I split them to two columns `<div class="col-md-6">`, you can see my code (open it in a full page):

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Data Office Registers</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS files for Jquery/Jquery-ui -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
  .box {
     background-color: #3C8DBC;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid white;
     height: 80px;
   }



h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.4125rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}
My result
  </style>
    </head>
    <body >
   <div class="row mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card-body">
       <div id="id" style="display: none;">2 </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/"> Dr Jeslin's Clinic</a>
        </h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Label: <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/">jeslinclinic</a></h6>
           <p class="card-text">Phone: <a href="tel:9">9</a></p>
           <p class="card-text">About Clinic: Dr Jeslin's Eye Clinic is a topnotch Eye Clinic</p>
           <p class="card-text"><a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/">Homepage</a></p>
           <p class="card-text">External Website: <a href="https://mysite">https://mysite</a></p>
        <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/editclinic" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
         </a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/live" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Waiting</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/seen" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Seen</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/register" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Register</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/checkin" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Checkin</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/doctor/edit/slots/2" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i> Consultation Time</a>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="w-100"></div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="w-100"></div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
       <div class="box col">Column</div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am adding an example of flex layout (I believe you need to adjust some changes for better display, this is just an example):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Data Office Registers</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS files for Jquery/Jquery-ui -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
  .box {
     background-color: #3C8DBC;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid white;
     height: 80px;
   }



h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.4125rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

  </style>
    </head>
    <body >
   <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 mr-3 ml-3 shadow bg-white rounded">
     <div class="p-2 flex-fill">
      <div class="card-body">
       <div id="id" style="display: none;">2 </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/"> Dr Jeslin's Clinic</a>
        </h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Label: <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/">jeslinclinic</a></h6>
           <p class="card-text">Phone: <a href="tel:9">9</a></p>
           <p class="card-text">About Clinic: Dr Jeslin's Eye Clinic is a topnotch Eye Clinic</p>
           <p class="card-text"><a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/">Homepage</a></p>
           <p class="card-text">External Website: <a href="https://mysite">https://mysite</a></p>
        <div id="docbtngp" class="d-flex flex-row">
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/editclinic" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
         </a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/live" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Waiting</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/seen" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Seen</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/register" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Register</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/checkin" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Checkin</a>
         <a href="/clinic/jeslinclinic/doctor/edit/slots/2" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mybtndocedit" data-id="2">
           <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i> Consultation Time</a>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="p-2 flex-fill">
     
        <div class="d-flex">
       <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
       <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
       <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
        </div>
       <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
        <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
        <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
       </div>
       <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
        <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
        <div class="p-2 flex-fill box">Column</div>
       </div>
     </div>
     
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, this is a responsive grid. For example: if you will watch the result on phone size you will see that no matter how you will set the table it won't be at the same row and won't be flex. I will edit the post and add flex layout if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

change the grid block and adjust the css.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="box col-sm-2">Buttontext</div>
      <div class="box col-sm-4">Buttontext</div>
      <div class="box col">Buttontext</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
      <div class="box col-sm-2">Buttontext</div>
      <div class="box col-sm-4">Buttontext</div>
      <div class="box col">Buttontext</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
      <div class="box col-sm-2">Buttontext</div>
      <div class="box col-sm-4">Buttontext</div>
      <div class="box col">Buttontext</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
     background-color: #3C8DBC;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 2px;
 }

.buttonpanel {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 45%;
     top: 0px;
}

h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.4125rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.row {
    height: 33%;
}
```